# spritekit + swift, change scene doesnot work good

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit, and I'm following some tutorial, but I got a problem which does not mentioned in the tutorial.
Here is what I'm gonna do, when I touch the screen each time, the scene changes from A to B, and repeat.

I have GameScene.swift and MenuScene.swift, almost the same code.
(Xcode version 7.3.1)
GameScene.swift:

```html
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        createScene()
    }
    
    func createScene() {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blueColor()
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.name = "label"
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
        myLabel.fontSize = 45
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:500, y:300)
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let nextScene = MenuScene()
        let doors = SKTransition.doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration(0.5)
        self.view!.presentScene(nextScene, transition: doors)
    }
   
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

MenuScene.swift:

```html
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        createScene()
    }
    
    func createScene() {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.redColor()
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.name = "label"
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
        myLabel.fontSize = 45
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:500, y:300)
        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let nextScene = GameScene()
        let doors = SKTransition.doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration(0.5)
        self.view!.presentScene(nextScene, transition: doors)
    }
    
    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        
    }
}
```

The problem is when I ran the code, it displayed the blue background and the text "hello world", which is what I expected, and I touched the screen, the background changed to red, but the text disappeared, then I touched again, the background changed back to blue, but the text is still disappeared, I could not find out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set size of the scene and scale mode. Try this code:

```
import SpriteKit

class MenuScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    createScene()
}

func createScene() {
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.redColor()
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
    myLabel.name = "label"
    myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
    myLabel.fontSize = 45
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:500, y:300)
    self.addChild(myLabel)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let nextScene = GameScene(size: scene!.size)
    nextScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    let doors = SKTransition.doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration(0.5)
    self.view!.presentScene(nextScene, transition: doors)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

}
}
```

and

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    createScene()
}


func createScene() {
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.blueColor()
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
    myLabel.name = "label"
    myLabel.text = "Hello, World!"
    myLabel.fontSize = 45
    myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:500, y:300)
    myLabel.zPosition = 2.0
    self.addChild(myLabel)
    print(myLabel.position)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let nextScene = MenuScene(size: scene!.size)
    nextScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    let doors = SKTransition.doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration(0.5)
    self.view!.presentScene(nextScene, transition: doors)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

}
}
```